# Python, blender and weird rotate behaviour after restoring matrix

Tags: python

I am trying to save user matrix and set it back later when needed
But after restoring the matrix the rotate function is behaving weird
As if it is 4D instead of 3D. And t seemt the wrong view.
What i did was open a default file and zoomed in. took these matrix values and placed them in VM. After restoring the view looks different.
I tried to search for similar posts but could not find any answer
Code i use is,

EDIT THE CODE ADDED

this is the code

```
import bpy
from mathutils import matrix

vm = ((0.9077774286270142, -0.4194521903991699, -6.8628960292471675e-09, 1.434309720993042),
        (0.3097465932369232, 0.6703528165817261, 0.6743027567863464, 0.9151758551597595),
        (-0.28283774852752686, -0.6121168732643127, 0.738455057144165, -0.902187168598175),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))


for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        v3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d   
        if v3d :
            v3d.view_matrix = vm
            v3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'
```

Before running script

[image]

After running script.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using `import mathutils` and `mathutils.Matrix()` to declare your matrix.

Comment: i already have mathutils imported but how do i use the mathutils.Matrix()
it gives the error mathutils not defined

Comment: That depends on how you've imported mathutils. If you're using the Python console, instead of running a script/add-on, then it does `from mathutils import *` for you. Therefore you don't prefix with `mathutils` and write `Matrix()` directly.

Comment: I uploaded the code i use (complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the `Matrix` class you can either use `import mathutils` and [`mathutils.Matrix()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix) to initialize an instance or `from mathutils import Matrix` and then [`Matrix()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix).

```
import bpy
import mathutils


view_matrix = mathutils.Matrix(([0.9077774286270142, -0.4194521903991699, -6.8628960292471675e-09, 1.434309720993042],
                                [0.3097465932369232, 0.6703528165817261, 0.6743027567863464, 0.9151758551597595],
                                [-0.28283774852752686, -0.6121168732643127, 0.738455057144165, -0.902187168598175],
                                [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])) 


for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                v3d = space.region_3d   
                v3d.view_matrix = view_matrix
                v3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'
                break
```

Comment: This is what i needed. Made a small adjustment to set the coords based on current view (so its not hardcoded) and works like a charm

I realized that i still needed to learn a lot Thanks @Robert for your lesson and time
Appriciate it